# Jupyter lab is overwriting text when typing, how do I turn this off if I don't have an insert key or a numpad?

Tags: user-interface, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The whole program is erasing text when I type inbetween something, I can't figure out how to disable this. Previous answers were unhelpful since my keyboard has neither an insert key or a numpad, so I'm not sure how this accidentally happened. There must be some shortcut I accidentally pushed and can't find.

I tried searching the settings of jupyterlab and couldn't anything relevant to disable this typing mode

EDIT: An onscreen keyboard fixed the issue, but I'm wondering what setting in jupyterlab had this enabled

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1203127/how-can-i-press-insert-on-a-keyboard-without-that-key

Comment: check the second answer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about using an onscreen keyboard. I would still like to know if there is a shortcut that was accidentally pushed

Comment: It might be unrelated to JupyterLab itself. There are ways to activate the "Insert" key from keyboard without having it on the keyboard via [Alt codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) or [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key).